# Npm list errors

Tags: node.js, npm

When I ran the command `npm list --depth=0` it returned this

```
+-- argon2@0.19.2
+-- body-parser@1.18.3
+-- cookie-parser@1.4.3
+-- express@4.16.3
+-- greenlock-express@2.1.5
+-- inquirer@4.0.2
+-- jsonwebtoken@8.2.1
+-- mongo-sanitize@1.0.0
+-- mongoose@4.13.13
+-- morgan@1.9.0
+-- nodemon@1.17.4                                                                     
+-- passport@0.4.0
`-- request@2.87.0

npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1                             
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11             
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6                    
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4               
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4                            
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2                     
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2                               
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
```

It returned a bunch of errors of which I have no idea where they are from.  I tried running npm install but that had no effect, otherwise, I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran `npm dedupe` and that seemed to completely fix the problem.

Comment: Worked recently with Angular 7 and the angular-cli after 1) creating a new project, 2) adding material, 3) running `npm ls --depth=0` (resulted in errors), 4) `npm dedupe` (resulted in clean results) *I also ran `npm i` and `npm update` before step #4 (`npm dedupe`), but was still getting errors.